# JavaMail API - Send Emoji/Smiley with Freemarker Template?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jakarta-mail, freemarker

I developed rest API in spring.

I have to send invitation mail to user with Emoji.

I developed .ftl and .java configuration file is as follows:

**invitation.ftl**

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
//Content
</body>
</html>
```

**webAppConfi.java**

```
@Bean
public FreeMarkerConfigurationFactoryBean freeMarkerConfigurationFactoryBean() {
    FreeMarkerConfigurationFactoryBean freeMarkerConfigurationFactoryBean = new FreeMarkerConfigurationFactoryBean();
    freeMarkerConfigurationFactoryBean
            .setTemplateLoaderPath("/WEB-INF/templates/mail/");
    freeMarkerConfigurationFactoryBean.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
    return freeMarkerConfigurationFactoryBean;
}
```

**sendMail.java**

```
    MimeMessage message = null;
    MimeMessageHelper objHelper = null;
    String strBody = null;
    try {

        strBody = FreeMarkerTemplateUtils.processTemplateIntoString(
                freemarkerMailConfiguration.getTemplate(templetName),
                templateProp);
        message = this.mailSender.createMimeMessage();
        objHelper = new MimeMessageHelper(message, true);
        objHelper.setTo(to);
        objHelper.setText(strBody, true);
        objHelper.setSubject(subject);
        mailSender.send(message);
        }
        finally{}
```

I get the string like that from iPhone \ud83d\ude14\ud83d\ude17.

So how could i send this emoji value to email body part?

Thank you!